# Event for Handling the Focus of the EditText

Tags: android, events, networking

Can anyone suggest to me any event related to the focus of the `EditText`?
My application contains an `EditText`, which accepts a URL in it.

Now my problem is that, that after the user will enter the URL in the field and Move further, without any of the click events, i.e when the focus will move from the `EditText`, it should detect the entered Url and goes to the server.

If I get the reply using Json Parsing, then it'll be more convenient.

Answer (score 554):

Here is the focus listener example.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lost the focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In fragments inside focus change listener i am unable to update my UI, any idea?

Comment: This does not work. If the keyboard was hide by "enter" or hide keyboard button on some devices, the "lost the focus" won't be fired. If you focus on edit text again, it won't file "got the focus" either.

Comment: Be aware that if you have your layout set to resize when the soft keyboard is displayed, or do something ui-related using a TextWatcher, the listener may get called a lot - even twice for each character typed! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727248/edittext-loses-focus-when-keyboard-appears-requires-touching-twice-to-edit

Answer (score 37):

When in Kotlin it will look like this:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        toast("focused")
    } else {
        toast("focuse lose")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

1. Declare object of EditText on top of class:

   ```
   EditText myEditText;
   ```
2. Find EditText in onCreate Function and setOnFocusChangeListener of EditText:

   ```
   myEditText = findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextNameInxml); 

   myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus) {
                         Toast.makeText(this, "Focus Lose", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Get Focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
   ```

It works fine.

Answer (score 4):

For those of us who this above valid solution didnt work, there's another workaround here

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocused) {
            if(!isFocused)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"not focused",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked but I dont understand y above solution didnt work for me