# Unclickable EditText in Tabactivity on 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-edittext

This is on of application activities, a `TabActivity` with some views and a TabHOST inside,

[image]

Its works fine on Android 2.2 devices,but in 4.2.2 i have this problem, when i try to click on my editText, nothing heppens it just doesn't receive focus and i can't modify it, any idea

Answer (score 0):

Did you try forcing the  focus and opening the Keyboard? something like this?

```
    edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
.showSoftInput(edit_Text, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lost the focus", 2000).show();
}
});
```

check out this post [edittext force focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025927/how-come-the-android-soft-keyboard-is-not-responding-to-edittext)  hope it helps