# Java Using Method from Different Class for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

I'm very new to Java and OOP. Here is what I've got:

```
public class AmountChanged implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void notFocused(View edittext1, boolean focused) {

//Do this awesome stuff

}
```

How do I instantiate and use this on one of my editText boxes in the mainActivity? I have already declared the editText boxes in the onCreate method.

Comment: what you want to achieve?please be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class where you are writing the code for the editext,in that activity's `onCreate()` method, you need to write

```
yourEditext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new AmountChanged());
```

[**Also give an eye to this please**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397391/event-for-handling-the-focus-of-the-edittext) as you can use anonymous  classes too.

Comment: Pleasure was all mine.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you created an `EditBox`:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
```

To set focus change listener, you should provide `OnFocusChangeListener` instance to the `setOnFocusChangeListener`. Since  `AmountChanged` implements `OnFocusChangeListener`, you can do the following:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new AmountChanged());
```

If you are going to use the same listener on many `EditText` items, you can save this listener as a variable somewhere:

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener myListener = new AmountChanged();
...
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(myListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreate` method where you have the `editText` box(es) you want to use this with,

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener ac = new AmountChanged();
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(ac);
```

From the [`View` Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html),

> **Set up listeners:** Views allow clients to set listeners that will be notified when something interesting happens to the view. For example, all views will let you set a listener to be notified when the view gains or loses focus. You can register such a listener using [`setOnFocusChangeListener(View.OnFocusChangeListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener)). Other view subclasses offer more specialized listeners. For example, a `Button` exposes a listener to notify clients when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Listener in android means that it is gonna listen to some event(`OnTouchListener`, `OnClickListener`, `OnFocusChangedListener` etc.). As you see `OnFocusChangedListener` interface is announced inside `View` class, in scope of Android it usually means that any child of `View` can produce this event, so you need to "listen" to those events.

In scope of EdiText what you have to do is something like this:

`editText.setOnFocusChangedListener(new AmmountChanged());`

`EdiText` is a child of View. So we are start "listening" to all OnFocusChanged events that will happen inside editText by registering our instance implementation OnFocusChangeListener.