# Set fragment edittext value from dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to create searchdate. Here is what i do here is `RijekSearch.java`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rijek_search, container, false);
    EditText start = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.startdateval);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment myDialogFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            myDialogFragment.show(fm, "dialog_fragment");
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

and here is`DatePickerFragment`

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());


        Fragment fr =   new RijekSearch();
        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("startval", formattedDate);
        fr.setArguments(args);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
        ft.commit();

    }
}
```

So. First i open the `RijekSearch` which is a fragment.  then after i click `start` (EditText) it will show `dialogfragment` (DatePickerFragment). There is no problem with showing and there is no error.

My problem is , how can i set the `start` value after i choose the date from my `DatePickerFragment` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `EditText` data one `Fragment` to `DialogFragment`

First remove this `start.setOnClickListener()` you can use these

1 -[on Text Change Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener)

2 - [FocusChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397391/event-for-handling-the-focus-of-the-edittext)

3 -[Search and handle its click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205339/android-how-to-make-keyboard-enter-button-say-search-and-handle-its-click)

on Action  pass `EditText` data

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("key", "value");
DialogFragment newFragment = new YourDialogFragment();  
newFragment.setArguments(args);
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
```

and get value in `DialogFragment`

```
Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
String myValue = mArgs.getString("key");
```

Comment: if i change my `start.setOnClickListener()` how can i open the dialogfragment ?

Comment: you can use any one from 3options which i post in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do so:
1. Create a public static editText(Not Recommended, memory leaks).
2. Create listener and pass the instance in the dialog fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Create interface `DateCallback`

```
interface DateCallback{
  void onDateSet(String fDate);
}
```

Aquire this in `DialogFragment` params

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private static DataCallback dataCallback;

    public static DatePickerFragment  newInstance(DataCallback dataCallback){
      this.dataCallback = dataCallback;
     return new DatePickerFragment();
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        dataCallback.onDateSet(formattedDate);
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Now in your RijekSearch

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            DatePickerFragment myDialogFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(new DateCallback(){
                  @Override
                  public void onDateSet(String fDate){
                     start.setText(fDate);
                  }
            });
            myDialogFragment.show(fm, "dialog_fragment");
        }
    });
```

Comment: in this part `  this.dataCallback = dataCallback;` i get an error  `cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: `dataCallback` should be static as mentioned